# Use customs variables for ecommerce tracking

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I want to have more specifics informations about a transaction
Actually, I used the basic code, that I put on my last transaction page (confirmation):

```
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
  '$!{Transactionid}',           // transaction ID
  'Womens Apparel', // affiliation or store name
  '$!{pvAmount}',          // total
  '$!{taxesPrice}',           // tax
  '15.00',          // shipping
  'San Jose',       // city
  'California',     // state or province
  'USA'             // country
]);
```

However I have others informations on this page (about the passenger), like client name, his email, his zipcode etc...
What is the best way to catch more information? I heard that I can put what I want in "affiliation" field, but it's only one slot available.
Can i use customs variables (declared before my trackpageview) :

```
gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'Name','$CLIENT_NAME', 1]);

gaq.push(['_trackPageview' ]);

gaq.push(['_addTrans', ]);

gaq.push(['_addItem', ]);

gaq.push(['_trackTrans' ]);
```

Comment: You must not store data that can identify a person in Google Analytics (that's part the GA terms of service). So while you could use custom vars you are not allowed to.

Comment: ok for name/firstname, but same for email?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, under any circumstances, send Personally Identifiable Information (PII) to GA's servers, so you should tread very carefully: it's not a question of using custom variables, it's a question of knowing with certainty that the information you're tracking can't be construed to be PII.

Google are a bit dodgy on the issue themselves. GUIDs, IDs, hashes, email addresses, address data, and a few other bits are forbidden more or less explicitly; but the ga.js implementation of eCommerce leaves you a slot for a transaction ID, which can be made to become PII, or, at minimum, is a field similar in kind to forbidden fields.

They get to be dodgy, we have to be careful. If you have any reason to believe that the data you're capturing can, in any way, be construed to be, or to point back to, PII, then omit it. It's not worth having your account shut down and your data wiped.

Answer (score 0):

Well its not possible to track. Custom Variable can help you :
Tracking Coupon Codes/ Promotional Codes ,  Payment Method, Shipping Method or more.

If you want to know utilize custom vaiable power for these purpose then go to http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/06/14/5-google-analytics-custom-variables-for-ecommerce/

Comment: thanks for the link, I just have one more question : if I want 3 more informations, like reference of reservation (PNR), departure & arrival cities, could I just do:
gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'PNR','$PNR', 2]);
gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'Departure','$departure', 2]);
gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3,'Arrival','$Arrival', 2]);
then I'll do my gaq.ush for trackpageView, addtrans, additem and tracktrans?